# Request for an example about state-of-the-art file reading in C++ 11

Tags: c++, stl, binaryfiles

There are tons of examples about file reading on the web. Many examples use plain old C-style file reading. Other examples use C++ stuff, but I have no idea whether it's just another average programmer writing a tutorial or whether it's real good modern C++.

So, the question is: How does a good C++ programmer nowadays solve the following tasks?

1. Read some bytes representing a single, primitive type variable from a binary file.
2. Read an array of known primitive type of known (but not constant) length.
3. Read an array of bytes when the type is not yet known, but the length in bytes is known. For example, if the array is read from the file and then passed to a function which actually builds an object from it.

Comment: Not a good idea combining several questions, IMO. At least some of them are duplicates, AFAIK.

Comment: Are you writing a C program? Then use C-style reading. Are you using C++? Then use C++ *stuff*. For now the best method of reading is the the method that works. Found it on your tutorials? It works? Use it. Later, when performance is critical, you can explore more advance IO techniques like async or getting the support of the OS. For now use the one that works correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, its probably not duplicate. I did not find anything that really points out GOOD C++ binary file reading. Not in the web, not at Stackoverflow. There are tons of examples using C-style.

Comment: @Michael really? Just search "c++ binary read" on the *web* and you got more than you can read in a week.

Comment: You ahouls also learn about (c++) data serialization.

Comment: Still, I'm not asking about HOW to do it. I'm asking about whats GOOD PRACTICE. That's not reflected in very most tutorials, particularly when it comes to the use of newer features.

Comment: @Michael then this is a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does a good C++ programmer nowadays solve the following tasks?
>
> 1.Read some bytes representing a single, primitive type variable from a binary file.

Use std::istream::read, if you want to "read some bytes representing a type". Use `operator >>` to read *an instance* of the type (you will have to implement this operator yourself for non-native types, but this is the way to do it).

> 2.Read an array of known primitive type of known (but not constant) length.

```
std::vector<YourType> YourVector;
KnownElementsCount = 100;
std::copy_n(std::istream_operator<YourType>{ in }, KnownElementsCount,
    std::back_inserter(YourVector));
```

If you want to read array of values of *unknown* length:

```
std::vector<YourType> YourVector;
std::copy(std::istream_operator<YourType>{ in }, std::istream_operator<YourType>{},
    std::back_inserter(YourVector));
```

> 3.Read an array of bytes when the type is not yet known, but the length in bytes is known. For example, if the array is read from the file and then passed to a function which actually builds an object from it.

Use std::istream::read; then, construct your object from the data.

Comment: I don't think you mean "non-POD types", `struct Foo { int i; char c; }` is a POD type, but I still need to implement `operator>>` for it myself.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, no - I meant trivial types. Thanks.

Comment: my `Foo` is also a trivial type! :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely, true. I meant non-composite types (types that have an operator>> for output, defined in the standard library). _sigh_ I've confused PoD with trivial and non-composite before.